# Get items permissions in OneDrive for Business using microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

**Context**

I'm trying to get the permissions granted on items in personal `OneDrive` for Business drives using the `Graph RESTful API`.

Querying the `OneDrive` for Business:

```
GET: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveID>/items/<itemID>/permissions.
```

and :

```
GET :graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveID>/root/permissions/<itemID>
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
"code": "-2130575138, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
"message": "MountPoint security error: host web isn't a personal site"
```

However, if I send the following request :

```
GET: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/root/permissions
```

I get the permissions on my Sharepoint online site. 
So it works for sharepoint online but not for OneDrive.

**Question**

How can I retrieve full permissions info using the `Graph REST API`?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing another example (after 'However, if I send the following request'). Did you have a scenario that did seem to work?

Comment: In the response headers you'll find a request-id header. If you can include the value from that header I can take a look at what's going on here.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for responding. 
Brad: I've added the missing example: 
However, if I send the following request :

    GET: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/root/permissions

I get the permissions on my Sharepoint online site. 
So it works for sharepoint online but not for OneDrive for Business.  

RGregg: This is the request-id from the response header:
 1ef8296c-b4e8-4051-b64a-923ecc733379

Comment: Can you also send the timestamp please?  We always need the timestamp and the request-id from the response header.

Comment: Response Headers:
Cache-Control:
private
Transfer-Encoding:
chunked
Content-Type:
application/json
Server:
Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id:
12bf547d-a425-4ab9-a9f7-9854f0484870
client-request-id:
12bf547d-a425-4ab9-a9f7-9854f0484870
x-ms-ags-diagnostic:
{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_3","ADSiteName":"SAN"}}
OutBoundDuration:
1345.5894
Duration:
1359.6689
X-Powered-By:
ASP.NET
Date:
Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:22:24 GMT

Comment: Hanan, how are you determining the driveId? for the signed in user please use: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive for any other user graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/drive

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how. 
You can get the drive id also through the OneDrive v2.0 API. using : 
https://{tenant_name}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{username_Domain_Name}/_api/v2.0/drive/
but it's the same. 

The drive id is alright, there's something else.