# How can I get permissions for an item from OneDrive for Business using REST?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, onedrive

I have utilized the [OneDrive JS picker](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm) and after the user selects an item, it will query for the permissions, using the route below, per the [permissions reference](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/permissions.htm).

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}/permissions
```

This works fine for items in personal OneDrive, but when working with items from OneDrive for business/sharepoint, the resulting HTTP response code is a *404*.

I tried using the domain of the sharepoint file (e.g. *https://sample-my.sharepoint.com*) but that didn't work either. Is there a different domain that can be used?

I realize this is similar to Hanan Levy's question [Get items permissions in OneDrive for Business using microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394461/get-items-permissions-in-onedrive-for-business-using-microsoft-graph-api) except that the response code I receive is *404* (File not found) while he reports the response has an error code and message (perhaps in response body).

**EDIT**:
Per the request of [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3570009/brad), below are the response headers *Date* and *request-id*, along with a screenshot containing the Request with response headers:

> **Date**:Thu, 08 Dec 2016 19:02:47 GMT
>   **request-id**:3b2fe7b5-7ffc-4cc6-9853-e13150297186

[image: screenshotOfRequestWithResponseHeaders]

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior? If so, if you can provide the value of the `request-id` header in the response along with the value of the `Date` header we can take a closer look.

Comment: @Brad : Yes - I have edited the post to include the response headers you requested, along with a screenshot from the browser console

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the call you're making is to `https://tenant.sharepoint.com` so I'm guessing you're trying to access the default document library for the tenant. However, the scopes you requested only include `Files.ReadWrite` which will only provide access to items in the caller's mysite. To access files outside of the caller's mysite you'll want to make sure to include `Files.ReadWrite.All` scope when you're creating the access token.

Comment: So that is set in the [App Registration](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList), under section **Microsoft Graph Permissions**, right? I added `Files.ReadWrite.All` to both the _Delegated Permissions_ and _Application Permissions_ (though the latter contains the text _(Admin Only)_ so I presume that won't affect anything? I tried removing the app authorization and re-authorizing but still see the 404 error trying to get the permissions

Comment: If you put a current access token into something like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) can you confirm the permission is actually in the token?

Comment: I tried putting the encoded token into the jwt.io decoder and it contains `"scp": "Files.ReadWrite User.Read",` so I am still trying to figure out how to properly add that permission. I have it listed under _Delegated Permissions_ and have removed the app permission in the sharepoint dashboard. Then when I sign in, the authorization consent form includes the bullet with text `Have full access to your files ` - I presume there isn't a way to see the permissions defined per their scopes, right?

Comment: do you have any response to my response and questions (from 12/9 and 12/2)?